# while doing upcasting how the below code will execute

Tags: java

When I execute it method portion is overriding nd giving subclass statement as o/p but variable is giving superclass value?also can u explain memory allocation for this?

```
public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            aaa bb=new b();
            System.out.println(bb.a);
                int c=bb.eat();
                System.out.println(c);
    }
}
class aaa{
    int a=30;
    int eat()
    {int x=60;
        System.out.println("CHEWING");
        return x;
    }
}
class b extends aaa{

    int a=23;
    int eat()
    {
//super.eat();
        int x=70;
        System.out.println("EaTING");
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will print 30, EaTING, 70

Answer (score 1):

Your are using "aaa bb", object 'bb' have no any idea about variable 'a' of class 'b' because "variables" have no override mechanism.

but "methods" have override mechanism.

Comment: Sir,thanks for the answer.Can u also explain how memory allocation happens to this program

Comment: object 'bb' will will hold a new type of class reference. suppose class is "CC"

class CC{
 int a=30;
int eat()
    {
//super.eat();
        int x=70;
        System.out.println("EaTING");
        return x;
    }
}

for memory allocation please read this file

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3su2zortrhmx60/Java%20data%20types%20and%20memory.docx?dl=0)